# Adding a button to a div which already used an innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display the score of the quiz using JS and also give it a finish button to send data to the database and return to another page. I can display the score test but not the button

```
<div class="container" id="quiz">
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<div class="quiz material-main">
  <h3 id="questions" ></h3>
  <div id= "audios" ></div>
  <div id="images" ></div>
        <div id="choices" ></div>
  <div class="quizBtn">
        <br />
            <button id="backBtn" class="backBtn" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 22px; background-color: #279; color: #fff; border: 0px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 20px; cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 20px;">Back</button>
    <button id="nextBtn" class="nextBtn" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 22px; background-color: #279; color: #fff; border: 0px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 20px; cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 20px;">Next</button>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="complete"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
if (counter >= data.length) {
           var score = Math.round(numCorrect/data.length*100);
          $('.quiz').hide().fadeIn("slow");
          document.getElementById('quiz').innerHTML="Quiz Complete! You scored " + numCorrect + " out of " + counter;
          document.getElementById('quiz').appendChild('<button id="complete" class="nextBtn" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 22px; background-color: #279; color: #fff; border: 0px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 20px; cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 20px;">Complete</button>')
          return score; // returns false *(there has to be a better way! figure it out.)*
        }
```

Comment: Anyways, where is the id : 'quiz' in html ?

Comment: edited. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Well, Why are you appending the complete to the container. Why not append this to the `<div class="complete"></div>` only , and that too using jquery in instead of this javascript stuff ?

Comment: I did that because I wanted to remove all the questions, audios, images and choices and replace it with a text of the results and the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appendChild()` is used for nodes, you can use `innerHTML` again

Try :

```
document.getElementById('quiz').innerHTML += '<button id="complete" class="nextBtn" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 22px; background-color: #279; color: #fff; border: 0px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 20px; cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 20px;">Complete</button>';
```

And don't forget the `;`

Comment: I've tried that but it displays the code itself for some reason

Comment: intereting, you updated the anaswer after mine answer 2 mins

Answer (score 0):

1. try `innerHTML +=`, be careful to use `append`, as IE doesn't suppor it:

```js
document.getElementById('quiz').innerHTML += ('<button id="complete" class="nextBtn" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 22px; background-color: #279; color: #fff; border: 0px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 20px; cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 20px;">Complete</button>')
```

2. try use local variable to enhence your code for speed-up:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('quiz');
el.innerHTML = 'sth';
el.innerHTML += 'another sth';
```